# What does this code mean in RedirectIfAuthenticated.php?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have seen someone added this particular code in `RedirectIfAuthenticated.php` and I don't understand how this actually works?

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
 {
     if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/home');
     }
     else {
        return redirect()->action('AdminController@login')->with('flash_message_error','Please login to access ');
     }

   return $next($request);
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In pseudo code:

```
if authenticated:
    redirect to /home
else (not authenticated):
    redirect to the url that corresponds to AdminController@login, flashing an error message to the session
```

The else portion does not exist in Laravel's middleware, it looks like you have added that.  That should not exist because that will lead to this middleware always redirecting someone somewhere.

This middleware is supposed to be used for 'guest' only routes.  So if you're authenticated, it redirects to 'home', otherwise, it runs the next middleware.

Comment: You mean, if the user is authenticated and credentials are found correct, he should be redirected to `home` else if credentials don't match he will be redirected to `AdminController@login`?

Comment: This doesn't do anything with credentials.  This just checks if the user is already authenticated.  Like I said, the else portion should probably not exist because why have a middleware that redirects 100% of the time?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am new to Laravel and am finding it hard to grasp authentication concept. I might sound stupid but I still wanna clarify this, when you write `if(authenticated)`, I take it, as in my case means, if the user email and password match, he is redirected to dashboard, the dashboard route hits `Auth` middleware. This middleware is supposed to filter this request but where does it do this filtering? And as you told me, it isn't filtered, thus, else part gets fired everytime.

Comment: I can't really understand what you're asking here.  Authentication is likely stored in a session, where as credentials aren't checked every time you load a page, they are only checked when you send your credentials and then a session is created.  So Auth::check() isn't checking credentials, it's checking if that  session has been created.  This middleware CANNOT exist on the route that actually checks your credentials since it would redirect before it hits that code.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I know about the redirection will happen before hitting hitting the route. Just to confirm my findings, the code doesn't form a session anywhere which is typically used to authenticate users. But we are simply using this middleware to redirect all requests that we get before hitting the route which fall in this particular route group?

Comment: If you have this middleware on a route group, none of those routes will work, since you're redirecting 100% of the time.

Comment: I agree, but then how is this piece of code I have posted above working? Can you please explain request flow of the above code. Sorry for taking up your time but I am not able to follow through. According to my understanding, in `AdminController@login` when credentials are matched, we are redirected to dashboard. Before hitting the route, we hit the middleware. But as you say the dashboard function in `AdminController` is never supposed to get hit the route then how is it working?

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding the middleware.  Why do you think this middleware is being run on any of those routes?

Comment: As per my understanding and what Laravel docs say, middleware is being run to authenticate the user request. But you just told me that we are checking if the session is formed which obviously is not formed anywhere so it is being used for redirection only. But then if that were to be true then how is dashboard route getting hit? Plz help me out with the confusion.

Comment: I don't think i'll be able to help you over SO, I think you may need a professional mentor or teacher who can explain it in person or visually.  Middleware is not run to authenticate the user.  The authentication happens in the login method if the request is a post.  The dashboard route does not have this middleware, the dashboard route uses the 'auth' middleware which does the opposite of the default 'guest' middleware.  Start with a fresh laravel project instead of using the custom 'guest' middleware you have in place.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help but plz explain this little thing to me, what does `Route::group(['middleware'=>['auth']],function(){

    Route::get('admin/dashboard', 'AdminController@dashboard');
    Route::get('settings','AdminController@settings');
});` mean? I see middleware before dashboard route.

Comment: You're referencing the wrong middleware.  'auth' does not use RedirectIfAuthenticated, look at app/Http/Kernel.php

Answer (score 1):

RedirectIfAuthenticated.php is the middleware which runs until you see the result of the request. It only checks if you are logged in or not and redirect to respective routes.

Comment: I can understand that but how is it overwriting the pages rendered by default auth command with custom pages and how does it do so?

Comment: Its not overwriting pages, it redirect to another controller function which has own logic or view.